# | Grep, Find which file the strings came from

Tags: grep

I have a set of PDFs, and I am running

```
strings * | grep message
```

This returns the strings containing that method, is there anyway I can get grep to tell me which file it is from?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `strings`, use

```
strings --print-file-name -- *
```

to get the results prefixed by the file name (like `grep`).

Comment: As a note, this will also cause grep to match file names that match your pattern.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unless one uses particularly weird file names, one can fix that by `strings --print-file-name * | grep ': message'` (the file names output by `strings` are terminated by `: `). The main question is whether the OP wants just the file names (then using `grep -l` only is better), or whether he also wants the matched strings (then `grep` will either complain about binary garbage, or output binary garbage, and none of these is helpful).

Comment: Correction: If the pattern "message" can occur anywhere in the string, `strings --print-file-name * | grep ': .*message'` is better.

Comment: (assuming there's no file named `foo: message` for instance)

Comment: That was one of the two things I meant when I talked about "particularly weird file names". (The other one is newlines in file names.)

Answer (score 1):

`grep` has no idea where the strings came from when using this method, because it never sees the filenames. If you want the filenames, use `-l` and pass the glob to `grep` directly:

```
grep -l message ./*
```

Comment: Note that you need an implementation of `grep` like GNU `grep` that supports reading binary files.

Comment: What implementation doesn't support `--`? It would not be POSIX, and I seriously doubt any pre-POSIX implementation would support binary file.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas If I recall correctly, Plan 9.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Nope, I'm mistaken, Plan 9 supports `--`. I just tested.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
grep -Hobae '[[:print:]]*message[[:print:]]*' -- *
```

That will tell you the filename and offset within the file of every printable string containing `message`.